# Recoding a column based off of a map/index that defines subsets of variables in that column

Tags: r, excel, spss

Up front, please excuse my terminology. I'm an MD/PhD student with little computer sci background and some experience with SPSS/R/Command line.

I have a set of patient encounter numbers and am trying to associate their surgeon identifier (AKA provider in the images below) with the encounter number. The excel file I'm working with has numerous rows of a given encounter number. Each row represents and individual item that was charged for during the patient's surgery (75,000 rows with ~1900 unique encounter #'s, example in picture 1 below).

**encounter numbers in excel file, without surgeon identifiers**

[image: Example of encounter numbers in excel file, without surgeon identifiers]

I have another excel file that has the appropriate surgeon identifier on the same row as each unique encounter number (picture 2 below). My problem is that my first file does not have the appropriate surgeon identifier next to the encounter numbers. So, I could manually paste over the right encounter numbers from file 2, but it would take me hours/days to do all 1900.

**surgeons associated with specific encounter numbers**

[image: Example of surgeons associated with specific encounter numbers]

I thought that I would be able to use my second file as a lookup table/map of which surgeon identifier links to which encounter number, so that I could generate a new variable or transform a copy of the encounter numbers into the correct surgeon identifier. To start on that, I concatenated the encounter numbers associated with each surgeon's identifier. The list is csv & for each surgeon identifier is in a single cell of excel as below.

[image: concatenated encounter numbers]

I can't find any question that addresses this..  Any insight on how I could proceed?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Your first screenshot seems superfluous as there is no information that matches data in your second or third screenshots. I do not see a column of encounter numbers.  If you want to get from screenshot 2 to screenshot 3, that is pretty simple in Excel. If you want something else, you'll need to be more specific and provide an example

Comment: Hey Ron. I've edited the question to clarify it. The first image depicts the file that I'm trying to act upon. Each encounter number represents a unique patient that underwent surgery. Each row in the first picture depicts a specific item that was used during that patient's surgery. I know which surgeons are associated with which encounter numbers (2nd file, depicted in picture 2), but I am stuck trying to figure out how to import the surgeon identifier into the first file.

Comment: Your first image has nothing labelled Encounter number.  Using a patient account number for the encounter number seems unwise on the surface as patient account numbers usually don't change; and a patient may have multiple encounters.  Hence my confusion.  In Excel, you can use Power Query to easily merge tables with matching columns, or you can probably use one of the `LOOKUP` functions, depending on what your data actually looks like and what you really want for a result.

Comment: The solution is (1) go back a step, you only need the original encounter list, not the restructured one. (2) look up the `match files` command in spss or `vlookup` in excel. Either of these will match up the surgeon ID with the original table - by encounter number (3) please don't try to do this manually - matching data manually in excel has caused tragedies before (4) if you clarifiy (and shorten) the question and get it re-opened I will be able to suggest real code